# The updated value is not reflecting in the html angular 2

Tags: angular

**app.component.html**

```
    {{loading_message}}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
     providers: [ApiBridgeService]
 })
 export class AppComponent {
     title = 'app works!';
     loading_message: String;

     constructor() {
         this.loading_message = "Init";
         setInterval(this.change_loading_message, 1000)
    }

     change_loading_message() {
        this.loading_message = "Executing"
     }
}
```

In html it always displays **Init**

**Expected result :**

It should display **executing** after a 1000ms.

Comment: setInterval probably changed the this to be global, would check on that.  you might have to add .bind(this)

Comment: try this line setInterval( ()  => {this.change_loading_message}, 1000)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Observables` (which you should), it is quite trivial to achieve that. I recommend an `ngOnInit` to 'kickoff' the observable at the point the component is initialized.

```
 @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
     providers: [ApiBridgeService]
 })
 export class AppComponent {
     title = 'app works!';
     loading_message: String;

     constructor() {
         this.loading_message = "Init";
     }

     ngOnInit(){
       Observable
           .empty()      //this is optional
           .delay(1000)  //delay for 1000ms
           .subscribe(()=>{  //subscribe to the observables!
              this.loading_message = "Executing"  //change your message!
           }); 
     }
}
```

To use the `.delay()` operator, you will need to import it:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
```

Note that the `.empty()` is optional. I like to use a `.empty()` to explicitly indicates that this observables is not going to return anything. If you are using `.empty`, you need to import it as well:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty`
```

More detailed explanation on [Observables.delay()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html)

Comment: How do I stop this Timer?

Comment: You don't need to stop the timer. What ever is in the subscribe call back function will be executed once the delay is done.

Comment: its throwing error **Property 'empty' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'**

Comment: You need to import it. `import rxjs/add/observable/empty`

Comment: sorry I did, import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'

if I import 'import rxjs/add/observable/empty' it throws an error.

Comment: now it throws 'Property 'delay' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'.

Comment: Oh my, I am spoon feeding am I. See edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145315/discussion-between-sandeep-kumar-and-cozyazure).